# How to keep wireframe in render?

Tags: rendering, animation, wireframe

Layout view is what I'm after for the final animation render.
The pictures show the problem and difference between the two.

How to keep the wireframe view overlay when rendering animation?

Thanks so much!

as is in layout mode
[image: as is in layout mode]

rendered
[image: rendered]

camera view within layout
[image: camera view within layout]

[[image: material][4]]

Comment: What are the materials/ modifiers used in the scene? Please [edit] and share images that include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it was the Gizmo/Overlay wireframe function that was making it look this way. When de-activating the overlay and adding the wireframe tool modifier I got roughly the same result I wanted.
This effect can be rendered via the view - render image/animation function within the layout.